# how set headers with RequestFuture volley

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I'm using Volley to make synchronous requests to a server. The following is sample how i make synchronous request with volley.

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + param, null, future, future);
    RequestQueue queue = NetworkSingleton.getInstance(ctx).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(req);
```

How can i add headers to request?

When i make async request with volley, i can simple override getHeaders method, but i really don't know how to do that with request future.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this but I put it into my application and it didn't throw any errors or warnings.

```
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "url", null, future, future){
        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
            String token = ApplicationController.getToken();
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", "token");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Since you're still doing a JSONObjectRequest, I think you can still override getHeaders in the JSONObjectRequest like you usually do.